# Pass value to property function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions:

```
zoomIn () { this.setState({zoom: true}) }
zoomOut () { this.setState({zoom: false}) }
```

that I pass as properties:

```
<TransitionGroup>
 <Carousel
    promo={this.props.promo}
    images={this.props.images}
    zoom={this.state.zoom}
    key={this.state.zoom}
    zoomIn={this.zoomIn.bind(this)}
    zoomOut={this.zoomOut.bind(this)} 
  />
</TransitionGroup>
```

and in carousel I use them like this inside the component:

```
onClick={this.props.zoomOut}
```

In reality, the zoom has a lot more different values than the state, so I would like to have just one function:

```
zoom (state) { this.setState({zoom: state}
```

I tried passing values like this, but it didn't work:

```
zoom={this.zoom.bind(this, state)}
```

Comment: Did you add a parameter to the zoom function definition to handle this new argument?

Comment: You might want to correct the typos in the title to avoid downvotes. (I tried but I cannot access the edit post link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the method passed in via props directly, you can ***define a local method*** for `<Carousel>` that handles the zoom onClick event handler.

You can then call one of the methods passed in as props with an argument passed into it:

In Carousel:

```
class Carousel extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    // you'll need to bind this to the Carousel component in order to use 
    // this.state properly
  }

  // new onClick handler that calls the method passed in via props
  handleClick() {  
    this.props.zoomOut(this.state)
  }/

  ...  // call on onClick (in render method or wherever you have it
  onClick={this.handleClick}
  ...
}
```

In the containing component you'll need to *modify the definition* of the `zoomOut`/`zoomIn` methods to accept a parameter:

```
zoomOut (stateArg) { 
  // do something with the stateArg argument passed in here
  this.setState({zoom: true}) 
}

zoomIn (stateArg) { 
  // do something with the stateArg argument passed in here
  this.setState({zoom: true}) 
}
```